# Cypher to sum dynamic properties values

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have some dynamic datasource property values on a node. There are around 5 datasources which could have one or more data sources. These properties are set via a [@Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference:annotating-entities:node-entity:dynamic-properties) annotation using a Map in Spring Data Neo4j. Once the node is saved, the values are set on the node as follows:

```
dataSource.ds1.count="10"
dataSource.ds2.count="20"
dataSource.ds3.count="30"
... etc
```

I want to be able to sum the values of these counts dynamically if they have been set and use this value to order the results.

Here is the some of the starting Cypher I have so far which lists the properties:

```
MATCH (n:Entity)
WITH n, [k in keys(n) where k =~ 'dataSources.(ds1|ds2).count'] as props
RETURN n.name, props
```

This returns:

```
╒═══════════╤═════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"n.name"   │"props"                                          │
╞═══════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"ENT1"     │["dataSources.ds1.count","dataSources.ds2.count"]│
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"ENT2"     │["dataSources.ds1.count","dataSources.ds2.count"]│
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"ENT3"     │["dataSources.ds1.count"]                        │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

How can I use the properties names to get the values and sum them?

I was thinking of something similar to this where I could use `apoc.sum` but am unsure of how to iterate over the property names to get their values.

```
RETURN n.name, apoc.coll.sum([COALESCE(toInteger(n.`dataSources.ds1.count`), 0), etc]) as count
ORDER by count DESC
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
MATCH (n:Entity)
RETURN
  n.name,
  COALESCE(n.`dataSources.ds1.count`, 0) + COALESCE(n.`dataSources.ds2.count`, 0) AS count
ORDER BY count
```

The [COALESCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) function returns its first non-NULL argument.

Or, if you pass the list of property names in a `props` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/):

```
MATCH (n:Entity)
RETURN n.name, REDUCE(s = 0, p IN $props | s + COALESCE(n[p], 0)) AS count
ORDER BY count
```

Comment: The second one does exactly what I need, thanks for the support cybersam.